# Dynamically mark dates on custom calendar

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsdate, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents

I'm using [Vurig Custom Calendar](https://github.com/TjeerdVurig/Vurig-Calendar) for my app. I need to mark multiple dates on the calendar but the dates should be dynamic i.e data from the json file (for which I'm using `JSONKit`) rather than hard-coded. How can I do that? How do I loop through the calendar to add the dates from the json file to the array?

This is the code I have so far:

**JSON:**

```
{
    "events": [
                  {
                    "event": {
                        "month": "10",
                        "day": "15",
                        "detail": "Some Detail"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "event": {
                        "month": "10",
                        "day": "25",
                        "detail": "Some blah"
                    }
                  }
    ]
}
```

**CODE:**

```
-(void)calendarView:(VRGCalendarView *)calendarView switchedToMonth:(int)month targetHeight:(float)targetHeight animated:(BOOL)animated {
    NSArray *dates;

        id day, month;

        JSONDecoder* decoder = [[JSONDecoder alloc] init];
        NSData *cdata =[self getJSON];

        NSDictionary* listDictionary = [decoder objectWithData:cdata];
        NSArray* events =[listDictionary objectForKey:@"events"];

        for (NSDictionary *event in events) {
            NSDictionary *eventDetails = [event objectForKey:@"event"];
            day = [eventDetails objectForKey:@"day"];
            month = [eventDetails objectForKey:@"month"];
        }

          //need help here to mark multiple dates in the calendar if month = currentMonth
            NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSIslamicCalendar];
            NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
            [components setDay:day]; //data from json file
            [components setMonth:month]; //data from json file
            NSDate *date1 = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
            dates =  [NSArray arrayWithObjects:date1, nil];


            [calendarView markDates:dates];


}

- (NSData*) getJSON {
    NSError *err = nil;
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
    NSString *filePath = [bundle pathForResource:@"info" ofType:@"json"];
    NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath options:NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe error:&err];
    return jsonData;
}
```

Comment: parse the json, get the a=dates, add em to an array and mark the array

Comment: way too broad. nobody can give you a concrete answer with code with so little info. Provide SSCCE for example

Comment: You need to provide a lot more information in order for this to be answerable. You need to provide info about the structure of your JSON data and where the dates are located in that data. You have comments in your code "data from JSON file" but give no indication what you mean by that. Presumably your JSON data will contain an array of records that include date fields. It looks like your method is supposed to be selecting the set of records for a particular month, so you would need to select the records for the current month.

Comment: I've edited my question. Please check.

Comment: You don't have a year available to you? How does that work?

Comment: The dates are Hijri dates. I have not added the year because I want the event for that month and day to be displayed every year.

Answer (score 0):

parse the json, get the dates, add em to an array and mark the array

one example (disclaimer written inline and with NO concrete info)

```
NSData *jsonData; // comes from somewhere
id parsedJSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:nil];
id datesAsStringsList = [parsedJSON valueForKey:@"someKeyWhereTheDatesAre"];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] initWithDateFormat:@"YYYYMMDD" allowNaturalLanguage:NO];
NSMutableArray *dates = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSString dateString in datesAsStringsList) {
    id newDate = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];
    if(newDate)
        [dates addObject:newDate];
}
[calendar markDates:dates];
```